# AES Encryption issue

Tags: android

I am writing encryption code for Android and Blackberry, using "AES/CBC/PKCS5" as shown below.
Android:

```
        byte[] encoded = {(byte) 0xA9, (byte) 0x9B, (byte) 0xC8, (byte) 0x32, (byte) 0x56, (byte) 0x35, (byte) 0xE3, (byte) 0x03,
                (byte) 0xA9, (byte) 0x9B, (byte) 0xC8, (byte) 0x32, (byte) 0x56, (byte) 0x35, (byte) 0xE3, (byte) 0x03};
        SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(encoded, "AES");

        Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");//AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding
        System.out.println("swapnil:"+c.getAlgorithm()+" BlockSize:"+c.getBlockSize());
            c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec);
            byte[] input = "Hello".getBytes();
            byte[] output = c.doFinal(input);
            System.out.println("Swapnil: " + new String(output));
```

For Blackberry:

```
        byte[] key1 = {(byte) 0xA9, (byte) 0x9B, (byte) 0xC8, (byte) 0x32, (byte) 0x56, (byte) 0x35, (byte) 0xE3, (byte) 0x03,
            (byte) 0xA9, (byte) 0x9B, (byte) 0xC8, (byte) 0x32, (byte) 0x56, (byte) 0x35, (byte) 0xE3, (byte) 0x03};
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); 

    try {
        InitializationVector iv = new InitializationVector(IV_BYTE);
        //SymmetricKey key = new SymmetricKeyFactory("AES_256", key1, 0, key1.length);
        AESKey aesKey = new AESKey(key1);
        EncryptorOutputStream os = EncryptorFactory.getEncryptorOutputStream(aesKey, baos, "AES/CBC/PKCS5", iv);///
        System.out.println("Swapnil"+os.getAlgorithm());
        os.write("Hello".getBytes());
        os.close();
        byte[] encryptedData = baos.toByteArray();
        String string = new String(encryptedData);
        LabelField lblField = new LabelField(string);
        add(lblField);

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (CryptoTokenException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (CryptoUnsupportedOperationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (CryptoException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

My problem is in Android when I run the code, even after having same key, it generates different encrypted data each time I run the code. While in blackberry, whenever I run the code, it generates same encrypted data. I think Android should do the same, but somehow its not working.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I wasn't calling cipher.processBytes() before doFinal(). So I I wanted to encrypt data of length 20 bytes, it used to return only 16 bytes as encrypted data.

This is the final code:

```
private byte[] cipherData(PaddedBufferedBlockCipher cipher, byte[] data) throws Exception {
        int minSize = cipher.getOutputSize(data.length);
        byte[] outBuf = new byte[minSize];
        int length1 = cipher.processBytes(data, 0, data.length, outBuf, 0);
        int length2 = cipher.doFinal(outBuf, length1);
        int actualLength = length1 + length2;
        byte[] result = new byte[actualLength];
        System.arraycopy(outBuf, 0, result, 0, result.length);
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

I am develop AES Encryption in Android and it is working fine for me.

```
public class AESEncrtptor {
    String strKey = "1234567890123456";
    byte[] byteKey;
    byte[] byteVector = new byte[] { 59, 12, (byte) 129, 77, 39, 119, 82, 6,
            23, 1, 55, 24, 12, (byte) 154, (byte) 224, 14 };

    public AESEncrtptor() {
        try {
            byteKey = strKey.getBytes("UTF-8");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public enum EnumCipherMode {
        CBC, ECB
    }

    public String Encrypt(String strdata, EnumCipherMode CipherMode) {
        try {
            String strAlgorithm = "AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding";
            switch (CipherMode) {
            case CBC:
                strAlgorithm = "AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding";
                break;
            case ECB:
                strAlgorithm = "AES/ECB/PKCS7Padding";
                break;
            }
            Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(strAlgorithm);
            SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(byteKey, strAlgorithm);
            switch (CipherMode) {
            case CBC:
                c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keySpec, new IvParameterSpec(
                        byteVector));
                break;
            case ECB:
                c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keySpec);
                break;
            }
            byte[] data = strdata.getBytes();

            byte[] encrypted = c.doFinal(data);
            return Base64.encodeToString(encrypted, Base64.DEFAULT);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return "";
        }
    }

    public String Decrypt(String strdata, EnumCipherMode CipherMode) {
        try {
            String strAlgorithm = "AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding";
            switch (CipherMode) {
            case CBC:
                strAlgorithm = "AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding";
                break;
            case ECB:
                strAlgorithm = "AES/ECB/PKCS7Padding";
                break;
            }
            Cipher d_c = Cipher.getInstance(strAlgorithm);
            SecretKeySpec d_keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(byteKey, strAlgorithm);
            switch (CipherMode) {
            case CBC:
                d_c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, d_keySpec, new IvParameterSpec(
                        byteVector));
                break;
            case ECB:
                d_c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, d_keySpec);
                break;
            }

            byte[] decrypted = d_c.doFinal(Base64.decode(strdata,
                    Base64.DEFAULT));
            String decryptedStr = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < decrypted.length; i++)
                decryptedStr += (char) decrypted[i];
            return decryptedStr;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return "";
        }
    }
}
```